# Can I change Linux time in a Postgresql production server?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Today I found out that a linux's server clock, hosting a PostgreSql cluster in a production environment, is late  and I need take it to the current time.

I've used these lines in my local machine:

```
sudo date --set="2017-01-19 12:09:59.990"
sudo hwclock --systohc
```

I've listed the time on PostgreSql

```
select now()
```

before and after the changes, and everything worked fine.
Is there any impact that I should look for ? 
Am I overthinking this ?

Comment: `Am I overthinking this ?` IMHO you are underthinking this: you did not solve the real problem. Best thing to do is to let NTP discipline the clock. (this does require that the machine is in some way connected to the internet)

Comment: You're rigth. I asked the infrastructure analyst to implement that.
I'm not allowed.
Tks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any problems that PostgreSQL itself would have with that, and jumping forward in time should not be a problem anyway – it is much like a time with zero activity.

Jumping *back* in time may not be a problem for PostgreSQL, but it might confuse an application to find future timestamps in the database.